# 500 when returning document on AWS EBS Spring

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have encountered something that i have no clue how to solve. Managing to narrow down what the issue was is a win on its on but still... Basically i have a class that implements AbstractPdfView and I use it to generate documents. After that I return it to the client and its downloaded. It is all good when i run it locally, but when i deploy it, it directly goes to 500, (faild)net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. Here is the response as well:

```
H/1.1 500
Server: nginx/1.14.1
Date: Thu, 02 May 2019 19:18:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: private
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Content-Disposition: attachment;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

I am not sure what else to provide, codewise... Question is - is there any protection over receiving files as responses? Could it be that the file is directly downloaded and not through a window where you specify where to save it?
Thanks.

Comment: Anything in the server logs about the http 500?  That might be the place to start. 
 From the AWS console, if you go into your EBS app and click on the Logs section from the sidebar, you can then request "Full Logs".

Comment: They all say the same thing - the error message that i have posted. And its all under access and not under error. But it cannot be an access issue since it is working fine on localhost... right?

Comment: Alright, i found out that pdf is not amongst the accepted headers. Now i just need to find out how to add it.

Comment: Basically, i get Content-Type text/html when it should be application/pdf. It is application/pdf when i run it locally, so if anyone know how to change it, please speak up :)

Comment: You can add "produces" to your request mapping annotation, e.g., `@GetMapping(value = "/mypath", produces = "application/pdf")`.

Comment: I would have been both mad and happy if that worked. It didnt. good call though. Under "Request headers" thete is this "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3". I do not see pdf here. Could that be it?

Comment: It's possible, but typically content negotiation failures do not result in an HTTP 500 at the server.  500 is "Internal Server Error" so that's why the server logs are usually important to finding out what happened. Have you tried turning on DEBUG or even TRACE level logs in your application.properties settings? You can add `logging.level.org.springframework.web: TRACE` and `logging.level.com.example: TRACE` (replace com.example with your own base package). If you use a db/hibernate you can turn on those logs too.

Comment: I managed to get it to show 415 and not 500!!! Talk about success standards... I changed the controller to this:    @GetMapping(produces = "application/pdf", headers = "content-type=application/pdf")

Comment: ..it is not working locally now as well. Oh my...

Comment: That "headers" setting is probably not what you want.  It restricts the _request_ type to application/pdf, whereas you want to specify the _response_ as application/pdf (which is what _produces_ does).  We're getting nowhere without logs, so I suggest figuring out why detailed logs aren't available.

Comment: Well its the first project that i upload to AWS and i am not sure how to enable detailed logging. Using the settings you suggested does display trace logs, but only in the intellij console. Excuse the incompetence.

Comment: The same level of logs seen in the console should be available from AWS.  In the beanstalk application environment, go to Logs, and there should be a "Request Full Logs" function.  After a moment, AWS will zip up the logs.  Download an unzip it.  The console log equivalent should be in a file called web-1.log or web-1.error.log.  There are additional logs in the nginx directory as well that might be worth checking out.

Comment: Both are empty...

Comment: And you mentioned that nginx/error.log was empty too, right? There's something very strange. You might want to deploy a really minimal spring boot app, even just with one GET returning "hello, world", just to make sure that can be deployed successfully.  Be sure to set the server port to 5000.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe it... Turns out I had a font (which btw I was loading from the project directory) in the PDF file and it wasn't recognizing it. Switch to a basic font, all good now... Thanks to @peekay for guiding me to find a solution.

Comment: Wow amazing!  Glad you found the bug!